# How to reduce white space on either end of chart area

Tags: chart.js

I am constructing a chartjs chart [as shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P47ac.png)

I am wanting to reduce the gap between the chart boundaries and the first/last bars. I understand each group of data is taking up x amount of space, but is there a way to make the first & last ones take up less space?